# Parametric integer solution of $aX^2+bY^2-cZ^2=0$

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and unknowns $X,Y,Z\in \mathbb{Z}$. How can I get the parametric solution $(X,Y,Z)$ of equation $$aX^2+bY^2-cZ^2=0$$ in Mathematica?

In **pari/gp**, this solution can be obtained by code
`M=matdiagonal([a,b,-c]);qfparam(M,qfsolve(M))`.

For more detail about equation see *H. Cohen, Number Theory. Vol. I. Tools and Diophantine Equations, 2007, p. 345*.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use Solve or Reduce like:

```
Reduce[{a x^2 + b y^2 - c z^2 == 0, {a, b, c} \[Element] 
   PositiveIntegers}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

[image]

You may plot the solution like:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[
  a x^2 + b y^2 - c z^2 == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
 , {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess $\mathbb{Z}$ means a set of integers (positive and negative), and  $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is a set of positive integers.

Comment: @Daniel Huber:  Looks like author is asking for $(X,Y,Z)\in\mathbb{Z}$